# Prove that $I + AB$ invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Let $A$ and $B$ be square complex matrices such that $A^3 = A^2$ and $A + B = I$. Prove that $I + AB$ invertible.

I am a beginner so I do not know how to solve it. Please help with this problem! Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

> Given : $A^3=A^2 , A+B=I$

Now $ \displaystyle A+B=I$ 
$\begin{align} A(A+B)=A,(A+B)A=A \\ A^2+AB=A,A^2+BA=A \\ AB=BA \tag1\end{align} $ $\begin{equation}A+B=I\\ \displaystyle \implies A^2(A+B) = A^2(I) \\ \displaystyle \implies A^3+A^2B=A^2 \\ \implies A^2+A^2B=A^2 \quad [\because A^3=A^2 ] \\ \implies A^2B=O \\ \implies A(AB)=O \\ \implies A(BA)=O \quad [\text{From} (1)]\\ \implies ABAB=O \\ \implies (AB)^2=O \\ \implies I - (AB)^2=I \\ \implies (I-AB)(I+AB)=I \\ \implies \det{\left((I-AB)(I+AB)\right)}=\det I \\ \implies \det{(I-AB)}\cdot\det{(I+AB)}=1 \\ \implies \det(I+AB) \ne 0 \end{equation}\\ \implies I+AB \ \text{ is invertible} $